# Internet Explorer 8 suspended and debug command line options

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, visual-studio-2010, command-line-arguments

I have Internet Explorer 8 set as my default browser and whenever I start my web application in Visual Studio 2010 with debugging it starts Internet Explorer 8 with the following command line arguments:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe -noframemerging -suspended -debug http://localhost:3198/
```

I've searched all over the place and the only options I can find on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330728%28VS.85%29.aspx) don't include the `-suspended` and `-debug` options. I'm curious since I'm having debugging issues that seem to get resolved if I remove the `-suspended` option. Does anyone have any idea what these two options mean?

Comment: well I ran the command iexplore.exe -suspended.....now I cant close the window its stuck on a connecting tab maybe . Maybe its something VS does to keep the session open in a way on the localhost?

Comment: Yeah its weird since just opening iexplore.exe with `-suspended` gives you a hanging window, but when opened thru Visual Studio it opens fine in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

Just a wild guess:

I think suspended does just that. It gives you the opportunity to attach your debugger to iexplore and set your breakpoints. After that you can start debugging by resuming the execution of iexplore.